# Calculate Transformation matrix for eneven Scaling

Tags: transformation, scaling, vtk

Is it possible to scale an object only towards one side? (see Image [Object Scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6sno.png))
If yes, how would I be able to calculate a transformation matrix for that?
I want to apply the transformation to a vtkModel.